# How to use multi threading in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to put a while loop in background and increment the value of count but the background while loop doesn't get update of count variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
((count++))
echo " External $count"
while [ $count -ne 0 ]
do
    echo "Inside $count.. sleeping 5"
    sleep 5
done &
sleep 10
((count++))
echo " External $count"
sleep 20
((count--))
((count--))
wait
```

Output:

```
 External 1
Inside 1.. sleeping 5
Inside 1.. sleeping 5
 External 2
Inside 1.. sleeping 5
Inside 1.. sleeping 5
Inside 1.. sleeping 5
```

Expected Output:

```
 External 1
Inside 1.. sleeping 5
Inside 1.. sleeping 5
 External 2
Inside 2.. sleeping 5
Inside 2.. sleeping 5
Inside 2.. sleeping 5
```

Comment: this will not run as written. Please edit to provide a [minimum, verifiable, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: Background is a separate process that can not directly affect the parent. Bash does not have threading.

Comment: @jeremysprofile  let me double check it.

Comment: @jordanm so how we can achieve this thing, any other way

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @RudiC Specifically I wanted to run two loops , one will shutdown a system and increments the counter and other loop should check if the system came back up again via ping etc.. and decrements the same counter

Comment: Looks like you want a semaphore concept - difficult in shell, AFAIK. Use a file, but race conditions may lead to unexpected results. You'd need a locking mechanism, too.

Comment: It seems I will have to use a file to write and read counter value if loop running in background can't see the update of counter variable dynamically.